# Cron job generates crontab.txt: not found

Tags: linux, shell, cron, python

Trying to figure out the reason(s) a script is not running properly in Cron.

Setup a shell to call a *.py file every minute with the following (Removed opening and closing # lines):

```
* * * * * python /root/job.sh
```

The job.sh runs a *.py file which checks an I2C temperature module and sends the results to Ubidots. It works fine manually. Tried restarting Cron (start, enable, and restart) and a few other variations such as adding username and full paths to job.sh.

Here is the script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python 
    python /root/temperature-monitor/main.py
```

The file has the following properties (also tried chmod a+x, u+x, 755, 666 and others):

```
-rwx--x--x 1 root root 62 Jul 21 15:07 job.sh
```

Checking logread indicates that cron it running:

```
Fri Jul 21 15:38:00 2017 cron.info crond[3464]: USER root pid 3491 cmd /root/job.sh
```

Created a log file and directed output to it with the following:

```
 * * * * * python /root/job.sh >/root/test1.log 2>&1
```

Output in file contains the following:

```
-ash: crontab.txt: not found
```

But the crontab.txt is listed in /etc/crontabs as root (filename) with the job listed in it.

Any ideas on what to try next? Just don't won't to have a script running in an infinite loop after startup.

Comment: You say “the crontab.txt is listed in /etc/crontabs …”. What is `crontab.txt`?  Is that the file that starts with `* * * * *` and says to run `job.sh`?  Is that the only thing it says? (It might help if you would do `cd /etc/crontabs; ls -la; cat -A crontab.txt` and ***[edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/381316/edit)*** to show the output.) Does any file ***say*** `crontab.txt`?  Please provide details. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From  crontab you are calling python to run your shell script (that's not a python script). change python to sh (or ash or bash) and I think you'll find it works better.

Comment: Update to `* * * * * sh /root/job.sh >/root/test1.log 2>&1` but still receiving `-ash: crontab.txt: not found` in test1.log, and Logread does not indicate any errors.

Comment: Was this string copied from a MS product like Word and pasted in a terminal session?

Comment: Grr, need to watch out for newlines in my reply. ... Was this string copied from a MS product like Word and pasted in a terminal session? If it was, drop into Linux, edit with vi or nano and manually enter the line. MS products do funky things with the characters (such as smart quotes and M-space and N-space) that they can mess up commands. I'm also going to suggest what Barmar suggest and just remove the sh. Does the command /root/job.sh work from the command line? Or you could replace the command with python /root/temperature-monitor/main.py >/root/test1.log 2>&1 and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Used `crontab -e` to edit crontab and removed the `^M` which were preventing it from running successfully. Now, it's time to get some rest.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put `python` in the `crontab`. It's a shell script, and python is run from inside the script. Since the script is executable and has a shebang line, you can execute the script itself as a command.

```
* * * * * /root/job.sh
```

Comment: Updated to `* * * * * /root/job.sh >/root/test1.log 2>&1` but still receiving `-ash: crontab.txt: not found` in test1.log. Logread does not indicate any errors.

Comment: I don't know what `crontab.txt` is, there's nothing in your cron job that mentions it.